# Renaming filename with counter in windows batch

Tags: batch-file

I want to change files from 1-example.txt to 200-example.txt (just change start number) with code below:

```
@Echo off

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET /a counter=200

for /F %%i in ('dir /b/a-d *.txt') do ( 
    for /F "usebackq tokens=1,* delims=-" %%c in ('%%i') do (
        SET filename=%%i
        :: Dunno how to fix
        echo !filename:%%c=%counter%!
        :: ren %%i %%newfilename
    )
    SET /a counter+=1
)
```

but it doesn't work, it shows **200** all the time. When I change %counter% to !counter! **it shows nothing**. How fix the counter?

Comment: Since you're tokenizing the file names you don't really have to perform string substitution anymore. You can simply combine the counter with the second file name token, like this: `rename "%%~i" "!counter!-%%~d"` Keep in mind that either method will not properly handle file names that contain exclamation marks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "Counter=200"
for /F %%I in ('dir /A-D /B *-*.txt 2^>nul') do (
    for /F "tokens=1* delims=-" %%A in ("%%~nxI") do set "NewFileName=!Counter!-%%B"
    ren "%%~fI" "!NewFileName!"
    set /A Counter+=1
)
endlocal
```

Just file name with file extension is processed as string by inner **FOR** loop because of using `%%~nxI`.

Everything left of first dash character is assigned to loop variable `A` which is of no interest because of being old number.

Everything right of first dash is assigned to loop variable `B` which is used to build the new file name with current counter value. The new file name must be without path.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `ren /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`